# Ubuntu лагает система

Tags: ubuntu

У меня Ubuntu 18.04 (LTS),система сильно лагает (анимация). Работать просто невозможно. Покапавшись в Интернете, я нашёл видеодрайвер для компьютера. Установил, назначил его как проприетарный драйвер, но изменений никаких не обнаружил. Что бы Вы мне посоветовали сделать (Ubuntu стоит рядом с Windows) (Процессор и видеокарта от Amd).

Comment: Вы бы хоть характеристики компьютера написали и в системный монитор заглянули, что ли. Простая фраза «сильно лагает» не говорит нам вообще ни о чём

Comment: Разрешение экрана 1366x768
Процессор E-350
Частота процессора 1600 МГц
Количество ядер процессора 2
видеокарта: ATI Radeon HD 6310M
Тип жесткого диска:HDD
Процессор AMD E-350 1600 МГц
Ядро процессора Zacate
Количество ядер процессора 2
Чипсет AMD A50M (Hudson M1)
Память 3 ГБ DDR3
Количество слотов 2
Изображение
Экран 11.6 дюймов 1366x768, широкоформатный
Тип видеокарты встроенная
Видеопроцессор ATI Radeon HD 6310M
Интерфейс накопителя Serial ATA
Скорость вращения 7200 об/мин

Comment: А теперь заглядываем в системный монитор и смотрим, кто кого нагружает

Comment: Gnome shell и gnome system monitor суммарно нагружают ЦП меньше, чем наполовину. Заходя в "Ресурсы", вижу, что нагрузка на ЦП > 80%. (Открыт только системный монитор, никаких других программ я не ставил). Может быть, это связано со второй ОС (Win7), которая стоит на одном компе.

Comment: `htop` что-нибудь интересное показывает? Там по столбцам можно сортировать.

Comment: Я решил поставить Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32 bit. Система лагать перестала. Как такое может быть?